# Rails link_to_if not hiding links correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, hide, link-to

For some reason my link_to_if line works, but appears on every show view for my model (Company).

Here's the code:

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to_if customer.company_id == @company.id, "#{customer.first_name} #{customer.last_name}", customer_path(customer[:id]) %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

The issue: I have Customer1 linked to CompanyX. When I go to CompanyZ it shows Customer1, but the link is not a hyperlink. it's just plaintext, and not even supposed to be showing up. However on CompanyX's view, the link works fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation of `link_to_if` (https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if), it clearly says that [if false] *only the name is returned*.

In the doc you can find that the (optional) block given is rendered in the `false` case. So in your case you could pass it an empty block:

```
<%= link_to_if false, customer_path(customer[:id]) {} %>
```

---

In my opinion, if you want to display the link only if one or more `customer`(s) from `@customers` are associated to that `@company`, you should do it this way:

```
<% @customers.where(company_id: @company.id).each do |customer| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to "#{customer.first_name} #{customer.last_name}", customer_path(customer[:id]) %>
  </li>
<% %>
```

Comment: For some reason the empty block didn't work, however from the docs `link_to "Login", ... if @current_user.nil?` worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: @SamLim I strongly recommend you to take a look at the second part of my answer as it will save performances. Cycling over all the `@customers` array only to display the matching `customer` for `@company` is a waste of performance.

Comment: Yes, worked perfectly! Thanks so much. As a Rails newb, and an additional question... should this type of logic be in the view?

Comment: nope, in your controller you might have something like `@customers = Customer.all`. Replace it with `@customers = Customer.where(company_id: @company.id)` to get the customer from that company only. A even better way (more readable) is to use `@customers = @company.customers` or even use directly in your view `@company.customers.each do |customer|`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to hide some records you can do from from controller to control customers based company

```
@customers = Company.find(:id).customers
```

then in your views you can just show it without to compare it

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to "#{customer.first_name} #{customer.last_name}", customer_path(customer[:id]) %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```